# AWS AppSync: Sync data across devices after app closed or without Internet connectivity

Tags: android, ios, aws-appsync

We want to synchronize some info across several devices of the same user.

Specifically, we want devices to be warned when a change is performed in one of them in order to sync the information across all devices.

This can be done with a subscription, but this only works when the device is online, so if the device goes offline and after some time goes back online, lose all this changes happened in this period

This can be done in a manual way: Querying and starting subscriptions when the app goes online. But we haven't seen how to do it automatically.

Is there any way to achieve it? Maybe some push notification or something similar?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the device is off line then you can't communicate with it; push notifications need a network connection too.

Comment: @Paulw11 I want the device to be warned when Internet connection is back. It is the case of push notifications: Device receive them when is connected again

Comment: Hi @jmartinalonso interesting scenario. I work on both the AppSync and SDK library team and would like to chat with you further if you're open to a phone call. Could you email me richthr_at_amazon.com (replace the at with @).